# VS2010 finding debug symbols when static libraries are chained

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Here's my setup:

A.exe -> B.lib -> tinyxmlstl.lib

A and B are in the same solution. B correctly finds tinyxmlstl.pdb, but A shows a linker warning about it. (LNK4099: PDB 'tinyxmlstl.pdb' was not found)

How can I make A find the pdb?*<sup>(without a build event that copies it around)</sup>

Comment: Is `tinyxmlstl.pdb` in the same directory as `tinyxmlstl.lib`?

Comment: Is the `tinyxmlstl.pdb` file in the same directory as the `tinyxmlstl.lib` file? BTW, I am uncertain if creating a .lib would require the .pdb file but I am _unsure_ of this.

Comment: Yes, `tinyxmlstl.pdb` is in the same directory as `tinyxmlstl.lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Debugging with Symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416588%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) has great indirect info on this matter. Adding the pdb path to the `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` environment variable fixes the issue although it's not as ideal as having the path embedded in the problematic project.

**Edit:**

Actually this solution only works when B is a DLL. When B is a static library...

> Currently the VC Linker require the PDB file to be located at the
>   exact location, and won't ever search any other locations.

However after doing some more reading it appears that this is essentially a VS bug that they aren't going to fix. Ugh. You get one of these warnings for each object file in the library, which means there can (and are) hundreds and it can't be suppressed.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that environment variable.